# How to get the exact IP address of the Restify server on listen?

Tags: node.js, restify

Consider the following code for rest API node server.

```
var restify = require('restify');

var server = restify.createServer();

server.get('/echo/:name', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send({name: req.params.name});
  next();
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

Running up that server with node:

```
$ node echo.js
restify listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

It shows `0.0.0.0` which is wrong.

Can anyone the me how to console log the exact IP of the server when its turned on?

Thanks

---

**Update**:
On executing the following code I am getting the below mentioned output, which is again makes difficult, which IP to pick?

```
    rest_server.listen(config.appPort, function () {
      var adrs = require('os').networkInterfaces();
          console.log(adrs);
          console.log('%s listening at %s', rest_server.name, rest_server.url);
    });
```

Output:

```
{ 'Local Area Connection': [ { address: '192.168.3.60', family: 'IPv4', internal
: false } ],
  'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1':
   [ { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', internal: true },
     { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', internal: true } ],
  'isatap.TEST.ORG':
   [ { address: 'fe80::5efe:c0a8:33c',
       family: 'IPv6',
       internal: false } ] }
restify listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: In this case, you should pick `192.168.3.60` because it's not internal *and* IPv4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the real address to the listen method, see

http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/#Server-API and http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_listen_path_callback

`server.address()` may return the address the server was bound to:

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_server_address

Comment: `server.address()` is returning the same 0.0.0.0.. Any clue ? `{ address: '0.0.0.0', family: 'IPv4', port: 8080 }`

Comment: Updated my question based on your inputs. But still not able to get exactly what is required   :(

Comment: the best would to start listen by giving directly the hotname/address. It seems it cannot resolve the localhost name. Are you on windows?

Comment: based on your answer I have derived a solution, just have a look at it.. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 5):

Had the Same issue and figured out the problem, basically you can pass another parameter to the .listen() function and that should be your server IP address

```
server.listen(port, [host], [backlog], [callback])


server.listen(port, YOUR IP ADDRESS, function(){ });
```

for you to get your server ip address just do "traceroute www.WEBSITE_URL.com" in the terminal.

let me know if you still have an issue.

thanks
Mahdi

Answer (score 0):

Got some solution, which is as follows.

Any improvements on the same is always welcomed.

```
var osDetails = require('os');

function getDynamicIP(calbck) {
    var ip;
    try {
        var adrs = osDetails.networkInterfaces();
        for (key in adrs) {
            if (adrs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (adrs[key][0].internal === false && adrs[key][0].family === 'IPv4') {
                    ip = adrs[key][0].address;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        return calbck(e, null);
    }
    return calbck(null, ip);
}
```